# MPI operations on private members of a Class

Tags: c++, mpi

I am wondering if you could use MPI with private members of C++ classes, for instance `void bcast` in the example below:

```
class foo
{
public:
  int rank;
  int size;

  foo()
  { 
   _isOperational = false;
  }

 void bcast(){
    MPI_Bcast(&_isOperational,1,MPI::BOOL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }
private:
  bool _isOperational;

};
```

All I am getting is a deadlock. Does this make some sense?

Comment: There's nothing special about private members that would keep you from using them with `mpi`.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] if you want help in debugging your application. Also please show your own debugging effort - e.g. if you were convinced this had something to do with visibility, you could easily change that and tried it out. Then you would have found out it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minimal reproducible example that demonstrates that private members are not a problem in MPI.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>


class foo
{
private:
  bool _isOperational;

public:
  int rank;
  int size;

  foo()
  { 
   _isOperational = false;
  }
  void changeOperational(bool b){
    _isOperational = b;
  }

  void printOperational(){
    printf("Rank: %d -> Operational: %d\n",rank,_isOperational);
  }

 void bcast(){
    MPI_Bcast(&_isOperational,1,MPI::BOOL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }

};


int main(){

  foo f;
  MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);

  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &f.size);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &f.rank);
  f.printOperational();
  if(f.rank == 0)
    f.changeOperational(true);


  f.bcast();
  f.printOperational();


  MPI_Finalize();



  return 0;
}
```